# Undefined object defined issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have done really good progress in my macros while getting the data in different URL's. with the code block below I am getting the error like "Undefined Object":

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim IE As Object, doc As Object
    Dim strURL As String, myDate As Date

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE

        For myDate = CDate("01-05-2017") To CDate("05-05-2017")

            strURL = "https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/" & Format(myDate, "dd-mm-yyyy") & "/monmore" ' Trim(Str(I))
            .navigate strURL
            Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Set doc = IE.Document
            GetAllTables doc

        Next myDate

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub


 Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim rw As Object
    Dim cl As Object
    Dim tabno As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim ThisLink As Object 'variable for <a> tags
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add

    For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        tabno = tabno + 1
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)

        rng.Offset(, -1) = "Table " & tabno
        For Each rw In tbl.Rows
            For Each cl In rw.Cells
                rng.Value = cl.outerText
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                myDate = myDate + 1
            Next cl
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -myDate)
        myDate = 0
        Next rw
    Next tbl

    myDate = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data

    Do While Cells(myDate, 1).Value = "" 'will loop until first not blank found in column A (starting from last row of data, from end to start)
        For Each ThisLink In doc.getElementsByTagName("a") 'we check all <a> tags
            If ThisLink.innerText = Cells(myDate, 2).Value Then Cells(myDate, 1).Value = ThisLink.href 'If the innertext is the name of the race, in column A we add link
        Next ThisLink
        myDate = myDate - 1 'we decrease row position
    Loop
    End Sub
```

the issue is in line :

```
 Do While Cells(myDate, 1).Value = ""
```

the aim of this line is that, continue to get the data from the links if the page has empty return. What is my mistake could you please help me? It is the last part of my work of macros. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of myDate when this happens? Also, fully qualify cells with the sheet name.

Comment: I suspect the problem is this  myDate = myDate - 1

Comment: As @QHarr mentions, myDate cannot become zero

Comment: yeah that worked but I am facing another issue which I wrote in last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you are experiencing may be to do with the value of myDate. It can't be zero.

If I do this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

Dim myDate As Date

myDate = 1

Do While Cells(myDate, 1).Value = "" 

    myDate = myDate - 1

Loop

End Sub
```

I get the Object defined error. I avoid this with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

Dim myDate As Date

myDate = 1

Do While Cells(myDate, 1).Value = "" 

    myDate = myDate - 1
    If Int(myDate) = 0 Then Exit Do 

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks ! I got rid off that issue but have another issue with date format . as you see in the code there is a code line like this : 

strURL = "https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/" & Format(myDate, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "/monmore" 


but when I change the mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy I get blank data. the case is that the date format in the link is dd-mm-yyyy. how can I fix that , do you have any idea?

Comment: That is a different question isn't it :-) Should really consider marking this as answered or helpful and post a new question which clearly states the next issue. Happy to help with that.

Comment: Your URLs are valid. I have tested them e.g. https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/01-05-2017/monmore is fine. It might make for an interesting new question if you can make clear what you mean by no data ; -)

Comment: the script's main aim is to automatically get the data by increasing day in the link and retrieve the new data from each link. link's differences are only on date. the PRoblem is : date format in the link is dd-mm-yyyy but in our script it is mm-dd-yyyy. that makes the script retreive the data for different months but not different days. it increases the month but not day and that is not I want actually. it should increase day not month.

Comment: you are hitting the Excel uses US date format issue?

Comment: yeah the script above generates the link each time like this : 

https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/01-05-2017/monmore/
https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/01-06-2017/monmore/
https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/01-07-2017/monmore/

and so on.... as you see the increased number is month not a day according to the link. what I need is to make it to increase like this : 

https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/01-05-2017/monmore/
https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/02-05-2017/monmore/
https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/03-05-2017/monmore/

and so on..

Comment: Have you tried CDate("2017-05-01") To CDate("2017-05-05")

Comment: I tried but it takes hyerarchy from this line : 

 strURL = "https://www.ukdogracing.net/racecards/" & Format(myDate, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "/monmore" '

Comment: Fixed. The problem was the UPPERCASE of the mm. it must be in uppercase like MM. and it worked. Thanks .

Comment: I’m pleased to hear it. Dates are a nightmare with excel